# spell check not working in Office 365 web app

Tags: outlook-web-app

I have noticed my spell check not working in office 365 outlook web app. When inspecting the HTML I see below:

```
div dir="ltr" class="[]" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Message body" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"
```

spellcheck attribute is set to false. I am not sure why Microsoft would do such a thing as this simply disables the spell check feature in the browser. Any extension anyone is aware of that I can override this on fly in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing extension for that purpose. However if you type this in your console, spellcheck will be enabled:

```
$("[spellcheck=false]").attr({spellcheck: true})
```

Comment: Thanks...but this is not persistent and will go away when the tab is refreshed.